# Counting the number of entries in JSON and executing the code accordingly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have an Json file which is include waypoints. The file can be have more or fewer recordings.

```
{
  "waypoint0": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint1": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint2": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint3": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint4": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint5": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
  "waypoint6": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",
}
```

First I want to read the JSON file:
std::vector route;

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                tr("Flugweg laden"), "",
                                                tr("Wegpunkt Datei (*.wpf)"));
QString val;
QFile file(filename);

file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
val = file.readAll();
file.close();
QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val.toUtf8());
QJsonObject sett2 = d.object();
QJsonObject it = d.object();
for(auto it = sett2.begin(); it != sett2.end(); ++it) { 
    //TODO
}
```

Now I want to execute code for each object with changes where `//TODO` is written.

```
est::aladin::Waypoint waypoint0; // waypoint0 should be changed on the name of the values like in my JSON File. waypoint0 to waypoint6
waypoint0.id = 0; // waypoint0 меняется в соответствии кол-во запись на waypoint1 и далее.
waypoint0.displayed_number = -1; // the first waypoint should be have the number -1 and the last -2, waypoints beetween from 1 and till 98.
waypoint0.latitude_wgs84_radians = lat; //first value from waypoint0 - in this example - 10.05456 and etc.
waypoint0.longitude_wgs84_radians = long; //second value from waypoint0 - in this example - 51.02453 and etc.
waypoint0.altitude_wgs84_meters = alt; //third value from waypoint0 - in this example - 0.0 and etc.
waypoint0.type = est::aladin::WaypointType::GroundControlStation; // if it is waypoint0
//between the first and last waypoint WAYPOINT+NUMBER.type = est::aladin::WaypointType::FlyOver;
//Last waypoint WAYPOINT+NUMBER.type = est::aladin::WaypointType::Landing;
route.push_back(waypoint0); // waypoint0 should be changed on which waypoint we will push now.
```

How to parse JSON line `"waypoint0": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",` and output to different variables.

Comment: We already know what you want, but what is your question?

Comment: @eyllanesc how to parse correct my json file and execute the last part of my code for each one waypoint. So it should read the file, counting the waypoints and substitute right values at right point. Im tryint to do this like 2 hourse, but Im just stuck. Chat for more statement will be better I think

Comment: And that you have tried to solve your problem, try it and when you have a real problem you just post a question. This seems like a requirement rather than a question. When you have a question then we will try to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc for me, it is a question, because I dont know, how to do that. I read lots of other questions and answers and just dont understand it.

Comment: I recommend you read the SO rules: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @eyllanesc can you just tell me, how can I parse JSON line `"waypoint0": "10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",` and output to different variables in my code?

Comment: Like any file, you must create another QJsonDocument where you write the output.

Comment: @eyllanesc can I get an example code pls?

Comment: To make it easier, show me an example of the output you want, as you have shown the example of the entry: the .json file.

Comment: @eyllanesc the json file is created not by code. I just want to read this one and parse each of my line and implement the parsed items into my last part of shown code. So `est::aladin::Waypoint waypoint0;` should be different for each line like `est::aladin::Waypoint waypoint1;` `est::aladin::Waypoint waypoint2;` and etc. The `"10.05456, 51.02453, 0.0",` should be saved into each `double` variable. So after that, my programm will send each waypoint to an simulator.

Comment: Okay I understand. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc yeah.. just pressed "ENTER".. I updated the comment

Comment: What parameters do you need to create an `est::aladin::Waypoint` ?, understand that this library is not well known or published.

Comment: lat, long, alt are doubles?

Comment: @eyllanesc  `std::vector<est::aladin::Waypoint> route;` yes, this library is not published. Yes, my Map Toolkit is using double for lat, long and alt. Can we go to the chat discussion? I can't create it myself, 'cause of rep. :/

Comment: @eyllanesc `struct Waypoint {
    std::int16_t id; ///< internal id

    /**
     * mapping:
     *      -2 -> 'L' END
     *      -1 -> 'B' Start
     *       0 -> invalid/no display
     *      >0 -> NNN
     */
    std::int16_t displayed_number;
    WaypointType type;

    double latitude_wgs84_radians;
    double longitude_wgs84_radians;
    double altitude_wgs84_meters;
};`

Comment: check my answer, if it worked, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @eyllanesc I will check it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .json is not adequate, I think it is a mistake to copy and paste it (there is an unnecessary comma in the last line).

The first thing we must do is obtain the `QJsonObject`, then iterate through its `keys()`, the result is string in csv format, so we must separate it with split, then we convert each item to double with `toDouble()`.

```
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                            tr("Flugweg laden"), "",
                                            tr("Wegpunkt Datei (*.wpf)"));
    if(!filename.isEmpty()){
        QByteArray val;
        QFile file(filename);
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        val = file.readAll();
        file.close();
        QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val);
        QJsonObject obj = d.object();
        for(const QString &key: obj.keys() ){
            QString line = obj[key].toString();
            QStringList elements = line.split(",");

            double lat= elements[0].toDouble();
            double lng= elements[1].toDouble();
            double alt= elements[2].toDouble();

            qDebug()<<key<< lat<<lng<<alt;
            est::aladin::Waypoint waypoint;
            [...]
            waypoint.latitude_wgs84_radians = lat;
            waypoint.longitude_wgs84_radians = lng;
            waypoint.altitude_wgs84_meters = alt; 
            [...]
            route.push_back(waypoint);   
        }
    }
```

*Note:* Do not use long as the name of a variable since it is a reserved name.

Comment: how to find out, which line I'm reading now? first or the last.

Comment: I already update my answer, but it is always from top to bottom like all text.

Comment: So I can't find out, which line I'm reading now? Cause it is necessary in my code, to make difference between id and type of my waypoint.

Comment: I did not write that, use the key variable to get that information.

Comment: `if(key == "waypoint0"){ //TODO }` correct? But, what if my last waypoint isn't 6?

Comment: In what order do you want to obtain each data?

Comment: Please answer, it is uncomfortable to wait for an answer for a long time.

Comment: Start from beginning and send each data with different id and type. Here is how my code looks now https://pastebin.com/wFFVS8xV sorry, to wait that long... got a disconnect with network

Comment: That depends on your logic and I do not know it or want to know it. I think my answer is correct, and I hope you mark it as correct.

Comment: Place int id = 0; and int number = 1; before the for, since it is being overwritten in each iteration.

Comment: yes, your answer is correct, can u at last tell me, how to find out with "key" which line Im reading at the moment? I never worked with json in c++

Comment: You can not know. Json is a format that does not interest the number of lines. Many times it is placed in a single line to save bytes since it is used in WEB, so the standard does not take into account the lines.

Comment: and I never can find out if it is the last line(value) in json?

Comment: No, and I do not understand why you want to know the line number, in .json you only need the data and what relationship you have with the other lines, json implements the structure of a tree.

Comment: because, the first line which I send to simulation programm, is the start of the first waypoint where the flayer should start. the last one, is finish. And the type of the waypoints - `waypoint.type = est::aladin::WaypointType::GroundControlStation; //for start` `waypoint.type = est::aladin::WaypointType::Landing; // for finish ` is different. So the other waypoints have `waypoint.type = est::aladin::WaypointType::FlyOver;`

Comment: Then I recommend not to read it as json but as any file and separate the lines, as if it were a .txt

Comment: how different are then this lines?  `QJsonDocument d = QJsonDocument::fromJson(val);
        QJsonObject obj = d.object();
        for(const QString &key: obj.keys() ){`

Comment: I do not understand you, different to what? The discussion is getting long unnecessarily, several times you ask me the same.

Comment: It's very different, you have to detect the line, detect when an element starts, and when it ends. Have you ever worked with a .txt file?

Comment: So I'm talking to nothing, learn to program c ++, that's one of the basic exercises. Bye :P